# JupyterHub instance depends on SSH pipe

Tags: ssh, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I have what I think is a simple question.  I have an Ubuntu server (14.04) running JupyterHub.  I launch the service using the standard command:

```
sudo jupyterhub
```

I'm doing this from an SSH connection to the server itself.  However, after the service starts my terminal turns into a 'logging only mode' (my words).  The jupyterhub notebook is available as it should be, but I loose access to the CL.  The problem is that the service only runs as long as my terminal is connected via SSH.  When I disconnect I can't access the service anymore.  How do I keep the service running so it will be available after I disconnect my SSH session?

Comment: have you tried `sudo jupyterhub & >>/dev/null 2>&1

Comment: awesome, works great thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `screen` or `nohup` to do this, though I prefer `screen` e.g.

```
screen -dmS hub sudo jupyterhub
```

This will spawn a new tts under your user. You'll have to go in there and type your `sudo` password if you don't have `NOPASSWD` enabled for this command:

```
screen -r hub
```

You'll see the prompt. Type your password and the hub will start. Press `Ctrl + A + D` to get back to your original command line.

This is nice because if you start having issues with `jupyterhub`, you can always `screen -r hub` to reattach and troubleshoot.